# Fantasy book about people in a journey who have special organs

Tags: story-identification

I mainly remember that it was a small group of people traveling somewhere and there were monsters that they had to fight off. There were people who had special organs put into their body, one of which I remember let them control electricity. They also had to make a special tonic or potion in order to maintain the organ.

I read this book one summer maybe 7 years ago. I think it was around the same time the first Percy Jackson book came out because I remember that book too. It was a novel and I believe that it was part of a series. It was in English.

The main character didn't have one of the organs (unless he got one later) but he was traveling with a woman who did have one.

Comment: When did you read this book? How old was it? Was it a novel or a short story? Was it part of a series? Was it in English? Any little detail can help! You may also be interested to read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: I've also read this book, but I can't remember its title either. I read it about 7-8 years ago, it was a novel, though probably not very long since I read it around the age of 13. I never read any sequel, so I don't know if it had any. The copy I read was in Swedish I'm pretty sure, don't know if it was translated from some other language.

Comment: @AlecS - If you have additional info, add it as an [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/124607/edit), not a comment.

Comment: @Philip If you remember any details that I don't please let me know so I can add them to my description.

Comment: When I first saw this, I thought it said orgasms.  Now that would be an interesting story. :-)

Comment: Probably related to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82049/fantasy-novel-about-a-girl-featuring-bottled-alchemy-trolls-etc/), though neither has an accepted answer.

Comment: I guess the organs would have to be special. Certainly, the average pipe organ wouldn't fit well into someone's body. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Foundling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Blood_Tattoo:_Foundling)* (2006), book one of the Monster Blood Tattoo trilogy by D. M. Cornish.

Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/210250.Foundling?ac=1&from_search=true):

> Set in the world of the Half-Continent—a land of tri-corner hats and flintlock pistols—the Monster Blood Tattoo trilogy is a world of predatory monsters, chemical potions and surgically altered people. Foundling begins the journey of Rossamund, a boy with a girl’s name, who is just about to begin a dangerous life in the service of the Emperor. What starts as a simple journey is threatened by encounters with monsters—and people, who may be worse. Learning who to trust and who to fear is neither easy nor without its perils, and Rossamund must choose his path carefully.

After an inauspicious start (being kidnapped by getting on the wrong boat), Rossamund meets Miss Europe, a fulgar.

> [**Fulgar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Blood_Tattoo_Series#Series_terminology) - a type of lahzar, who can summon deadly electricity from within their bodies.

The setting is summarized on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Blood_Tattoo_Series#Setting) as:

> Technology as we know it has been replaced in Cornish's world with a sort of blend of mechanical and biological machinery. For example, many boats and ships are driven not by oars or engines but by "gastrines", living, mindless organs and organisms grown into the ship itself, which produce the kinetic energy required for the ship's propulsion, and must be "fed" nutrients and kept alive. Other examples include "Leers", individuals whose sensory organs have been specially treated with various alchemical concoctions to allow them to sense monsters or when another person is lying.

...and at [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/MonsterBloodTattoo) as:

> Combine Bio Punk and Dungeon Punk, mold it into a Coming-of-Age Story, layer in a lot of Lord of the Rings-style world building, and frost it with lots of alchemy, and you'll have the Monster Blood Tattoo series.